# Controller or Manager as a Service?

Tags: web-services, symfony, architecture

I am being motivated for this question by Symfony, but obviously this covers the entire Software Engineering sector, therefore it is language-agnostic.

I have been tempted to create a Controller as a service so to make it available in another controller, but may be a better practice to create a service based on the manager of an entity?

Comment: Symfony 2 supports the notion of a sub-request which makes it easy to embed a controller inside another controller regardless if whether or not the controller is defined as a service.  Your question is not very clear.  More than likely you will want to share a manager and not a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a service directly ? I don't understand the point to use a Controller as a service if your controller as the role of a service ? That doesn't make sense to me but maybe I misunderstood your question.

You have different solutions:

- First of all you have to understand that your entity manager can be used as a service everywhere in your application. You can use it like that in a controller (for exemple): $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
- If you want to redirect your request from a controller to another one, you can use the forward method : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller

Here a link that can maybe help you: http://ahoj.io/symfony2-and-dependency-injection